# GWT + GAE + Multiple pages + SSH

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, ssh

I am trying to write an application with two pages where one needs SSH and the other doesn't (because of performance concern). I understand that multiple pages/entry-points are discouraged in GWT framework. But I don't know how I can turn SSH traffic on and off dynamically using GWT+GAE. Even though I think I can setup to use SSH all the time by modifying web.xml. Can anyone suggest a simple solution?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GWT and GAE are two separate technologies:

1. GWT: if you want to mix both secure and unsecure URLs you will need to have multiple pages / entry points. You can not have an unsecured GWT page making secured RPC calls to the server due to browser's [Same Origin Policy](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_SOP).
2. GAE: having both secure and unsecure URLs in GAE is simple - just create a proper [`<security-constraint>`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Secure_URLs) configuration in your web.xml .